# How do I bind a directive's property to a dropdown in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a series of templates in a dropdown bound to $scope.templates:

`[{"id":1, "name":"Test 1",{"id":2, "name":"Test 2"}]`.

I also have a directive,

```
<editor data-template="1"></editor>
```

Depending on the template selected in the dropdown, it should re-render the directive with the appropriate template. Is this possible? To date I've only seen simple one-to-one databinding of fields to divs, and nothing triggering a re-render of an entire directive. What is the best approach for this situation?

**Update**: Even more basic to the directive $scope, is cross-controller two-way binding. e.g. I can't seem to figure out how to keep a service object in sync across Controllers. What I'd really like to happen is for the changes in one controller to be available to the other controller and vice versa. http://jsfiddle.net/9gSVn/1/

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? With the 2 way scope binding in the directive it should be pretty straightforward

Comment: This is a pretty basic request, in which case I'd start here: http://youtu.be/iB7hfvqyZpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a directive that replaces the html contents when a scope value changes. [This blog post](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/) is very helpful in describing the steps to create a directive with dynamic templates.

[Here is a sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FmUU7/) with a directive that watches for model changes:

```
module.directive('template', function () {
    var getTemplate = function (id) {
        var template = '<div>no template for ' + id + '</div>';

        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                template = '<div>template 1 from directive</div>';
                break;
            case 2:
                template = '<div>template 2 also from directive</div>';
                break;
        }

        return template;
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { id: '=templateId' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('id', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                element.html(getTemplate(newValue));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure this answers my original question perfectly. Thanks. Still not sure about sync'ing scope across controllers, but that might be better asked in a separate question.

Comment: Another question would probably be best in general for Stack Overflow but check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gSVn/2/) if you bind to the object itself in your controllers (as opposed to the type property) it works nicely. Binding to primitives like a string doesn't work as well as binding to a primitive of an object.